# how to loop over all images and add border to all images in python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am working on image editing in python 3.7. I have a function which add border to all the images. But It returns only first image in folder and exists. This is my function:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now()
def img_filter(img_in,border):
    img = Image.open(border)
    background = Image.open(img_in)
    size = background.size
    img = img.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    background = background.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
    background.paste(img,(0,0),img)
    saved = background.save(f"./img/1{time}.jpg")
    print(saved)
    img.close()
```

AND thats my code:

```
path = glob.glob("./img/*.jpg")
for img in path:
    with open(img, 'rb') as file :
        img = Image.open(file)
        img_filter(img,'v.png')
```

please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` variable is global. So the value remains same for all the images. Either you can create time variable inside the `img_filter` method or you can create that variable inside the `for` loop and pass it as param to the method.

I personally would have preferred to create a `curr_time` variable inside the `for` loop.